# Custom Floating Text Field - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create a custom text field when I started to input label should float to top-left. I know there is some libraries to make that but I want to do it myself. I found some blog about that but these are generally make that in viewController but I'll use this format in many pages so I think I should create a custom text field and use this where I need. I tried to use codes in my custom text field but nothings happen.

There is codes which working in viewController :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabelTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabelLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        textField.delegate = self
        // Create a padding view for padding on left
        let indentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 10, height: 20))
        textField.leftView = indentView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always

        // Create a padding view for padding on right
        textField.rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 15, height: textField.frame.height))
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          floatTitle()
          performAnimation(transform: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1))
      }
     // This is where we adjust constraint and the label will float to the top
     func floatTitle() {
         textLabel.font = textLabel.font?.withSize(8)
         textLabelTop.constant = 7
         textLabelLeading.constant = 7
      }
      // By adding a little animation
      private func performAnimation(transform: CGAffineTransform) {
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
              self.textLabel.transform = transform
              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          }, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

[image: It should be look like this]

How can I implement this codes to custom text field ?

Comment: You can take help from this source code: https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that medium blog and use that for my project.

https://medium.com/sprinthub/creating-a-custom-floating-label-style-text-field-in-swift-f9f6aeaf39fe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).